# editing HTML in Joomla pages

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm no too used to or familiar with the Joomla system. SO I kind of need your help here. Here's my problem.
I'm building a site, but the template came with problems and the template makers refuse to accept they made a mistake. [AS Templates](http://www.astemplates.com/115) Don't buy from these guys unless you don't care about being on your own if something happens.

Anyway, basically, the site's buttons are all out of alignment. I tried fixing them through CSS but no luck. Some things can't be fixed in the CSS files because they belong to the HTML part of it. But as some of you may know, Joomla is PHP not HTML. So my question is how do I fix an HTML line of code in Joomla?

To be specific:

I have this code in my site

```
<form name="logoutForm" method="post" action="/"> 
   <button class="btl-buttonsubmit"onclick="document.logoutForm.submit();" name="Submit" style="">Log out</button> 
   <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option"> 
   <input type="hidden" value="user.logout" name="task"> 
   <input type="hidden" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0xMDE=" name="return"> 
   <input type="hidden" value="1" name="7b6cc3e246acff3e3943410a6f4919cf"> 
</form>
```

Since this is not PHP code or CSS I cant find it anywhere

Here are the screenshots of my two trouble areas
[image: logout button]

and

[image: search result form]

Thanks again

I'm re-editing this to add the code for the search results. Please review for me, refer to the screenshot as well to see what I see or go to my site and search for anything

```
<?php
 defined('_JEXEC') or die;

 $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
 $upper_limit = $lang->getUpperLimitSearchWord();

 JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');
 ?>
 <form id="searchForm" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_search');?>" method="post">

<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group pull-left">
        <input type="text" name="searchword" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD'); ?>" id="search-searchword" size="30" maxlength="<?php echo $upper_limit; ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->origkeyword); ?>" class="inputbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn group pull-left">
        <button name="Search" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="button btn btn hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH');?>"><span class="icon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search" />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="searchintro<?php echo $this->params->get('pageclass_sfx'); ?>">
    <?php if (!empty($this->searchword)):?>
    <p><?php echo JText::plural('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD_N_RESULTS', '<span class="badge badge-info">'. $this->total. '</span>');?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>

<fieldset class="phrases">
    <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_FOR');?>
    </legend>
        <div class="phrases-box">
        <?php echo $this->lists['searchphrase']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="ordering-box">
        <label for="ordering" class="ordering">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_ORDERING');?>
        </label>
        <?php echo $this->lists['ordering'];?>
        </div>
</fieldset>

<?php if ($this->params->get('search_areas', 1)) : ?>
    <fieldset class="only">
    <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_ONLY');?></legend>
    <?php foreach ($this->searchareas['search'] as $val => $txt) :
        $checked = is_array($this->searchareas['active']) && in_array($val, $this->searchareas['active']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    ?>
    <label for="area-<?php echo $val;?>" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="<?php echo $val;?>" id="area-<?php echo $val;?>" <?php echo $checked;?> >
        <?php echo JText::_($txt); ?>
    </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->total > 0) : ?>

<div class="form-limit">
    <label for="limit">
        <?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_DISPLAY_NUM'); ?>
    </label>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getLimitBox(); ?>
</div>
    <p class="counter">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?>
</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show inner file structure? I think that is theme to pay.

Comment: [CODE]
<form name="logoutForm" method="post" action="/">
       <button class="btl-buttonsubmit"onclick="document.logoutForm.submit();" name="Submit" style="">Log out</button>
       <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
       <input type="hidden" value="user.logout" name="task">
       <input type="hidden" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0xMDE=" name="return">
       <input type="hidden" value="1" name="7b6cc3e246acff3e3943410a6f4919cf">
     </form>
[/CODE]
I was going to add a screenshot but can't do it here I guess

Comment: can you publish the template somewhere so we can view the problems?

Comment: this sample code should be entered into an updated version of your post..

Comment: you can see the site at www.guhlmotors.com

Comment: what do you mean by out of alignment? which bit are you referring to? please provide a screenshot

Comment: you can see the site at [link](http://www.guhlmotors.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm yea I can see what you mean. The template does have some issues. And that is not only your problem there are many places were you need to edit your stylesheet. But it's very hard to eyeball all of them and wrap all the solutions in one answer.

But as an advice you can use firebug if you are using firefox or google developer tools by pressing ctrl shift j to open them. You can edit some of your content live and see the changes that are needed to be done in specific places and then you just do them.

For example I found at the section CONTACT the upper right banner has it title popping out of the template. The fix is located in /templates/as002035/css/tmpl.custom.css line 11 by setting the padding to 0 0 20px.

When Creating an account a modal box splashes into my face. You need to fix that by editing the width and the height of that window again by using those tools.

Finally i cant see the logout button " form " since I can't register to your website due to the mail that was not sent in my e-mails. So probably you need a developer to fix all of these things.

I hope I helped a bit.

Comment: Thank you themis. Actually I am the developer. I just never dealtwith joomla before. I always developed static sites. I'm ok with finding the CSS fixes for joomla. I was going to get to those bigs eventually. But I wanted to fix the HTML bug first since its the toughest one for me. I'm used to dealing with pages. Joomla apparently uses a database to store their code in. So its tricky. But thank you for noticing those bugs

Comment: No problem. Still I can't see the logout form because in order to see it I must login first :). Also you are referring to buttons but there is only one button. The rest are hidden values of the form

Comment: I am fixing the login mail fucntion right one. It wasn't instantiated.

Comment: ok, if you can activate me please manually from the user manager

Comment: Ok try to do it again. I deleted you. ALso, the banner title should be fine and the login button is also working in alignment cause I'm not using that module but there are other alignment problems I cant spot. Let me find them while you log on

Comment: SMTP Error! Data not accepted.

SMTP server error: Missing internal data in the header. Message discarded.

×
Warning

Registration failed: An error was encountered while sending the registration email. A message has been sent to the administrator of this site.

Comment: yep I am on. I see a white box on the bottom right. Now were are those buttons?

Comment: oh I guess that white button is the problem?

Comment: Well yes and no. ha ha They seem to look aligned in some cases and in some they dont. For example, right now they seem to be fine, But if you go to the contact us page and look for directions to the shop and enlarge the directions in a lightbox (there is a link for that), you'll see the bottom is out of alignment again

Comment: I am in chrome and I am getting an error 
Error: TypeError: this.overlay is undefined
Source File: http://www.guhlmotors.com/media/plugin_googlemap2/site/moodalbox/js/moodalbox1.3hackv3.js
Line: 24

Can't open that box :/

Comment: anyway I can't find one single problem. I wish I could help further. If you can provide with a screenshoot?

Comment: no problem bud. It is hard to communicate through this anyway. But I do appreciate your time

Comment: anyway I am moving on. If you provide with a screenshot the exact problem I will be around for a while. Also do this trick to your background since it looks good. background-attachment: fixed; in the body class. It will cause the background to stay static while the sheet moves.

Comment: That was great man! Thanks! I am contacting the server about this register issue and they actually told me to hire someone to fix it! HA HA HA! This is their server issue! I can't believe some people. And to top it off they have no complain number or email or anything. Its a dead end. WOW. ANyway, I guess I'll battle this some more. Thanks you again

Comment: Try to provide some screen shoots about your problem. Maybe we can work it out

Comment: It doesn't let me. I need 10 reputation for images. But I did fix the login problem. You may log back in and see the logout button issue

Comment: the logout has to look like sitemap and other links like the upper menu?

Comment: The logout button is fixed. The only thing left is the search results alignment. Try searching for anything and watch the results form. It doesn't line up. I added a pic up in my original question

Comment: ok you are referring to the com_search component. In order to change it layout go components/com_search/views/search/tmpl to change the layout of default_form.php and default_results.php and default.php. those contain that result I guess and if you are using joomla 2.5

Comment: quick update. I fixed the results message label. It is aligned right under the textbox. Have not tried on other browsers but I am hopeful. The last thing and I will be done is gtting that button up a little, which I can't seem to find it in the css files even with firebug. If I move it I move EVERY button accross the site up as well. But although that is not a big deal to me, wwhat I really want is to label it. I want it to say "Search" But neither CSS or PHP is doing it for me.

Comment: a quick way to move that button is to open /templates/as002035/css/tmpl.content.css go to line 1845 and add to the class #contact-form .button, #searchForm .button, #member-registration button, #user-registration button, #adminForm button, #component .profile input.button, .profile-edit button, .login button, #FoxForm button position:absolute and use negative top and left. But I am not sure what effect will cause to other places. If you can access that file add and test a class #searchForm .button{position:absolute;} to refer to that button hope that helps

Comment: Thank you themis, button is aligned. I isolated it and applied position:absolute and adjusted. I was trying my hardest not use absolute but I guess I don't have an option. Every time I use absolute it ends ups giving me problems in other browsers, and specially in other screen sizes and Mac machines. BUt it works on my android so I'm keeping my fingers crossed. Any ideas on why isn't the value="" property not working? The button is empty and it should say "Search"

Comment: A fast guess is to edit the language files. Probably the key of the text of that button was not set. Apart from that , can't you edit the view files?

Comment: I was just in the view files. I have to admit, I have never coded in there. Not sure how they work

Comment: Views contain the layout html that is generated by the joomla

Comment: OK!!!! Found the problem ! Phew! finally. This is what it said:

<button name="Search" value="Search" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="button btn btn-search" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH');?>"><span class="icon-search"></span></button>

Apparently it was trying to display an icon inside the button. Maybe the same one as in the original search button in the home page. I just added "search" inside those span tags and voila! 

I do want to thank themis and ricardo for helping with this. Thank you so much. Anything you need, contact me.

Comment: OH and by the way, for anyone reading this. Do not buy a template from [http://www.astemplates.com/] (http://www.astemplates.com/). These guys sell defective templates and do not stand behind their product. I reached out to them originally so they can fix it and they sent me away saying their demo works. Just cause the demo works it doesn't mean it will work with someone else. I don't normally do this to anyone, but I would be doing a diservice to other fellow website designers if I didnt mention this. SO unless, you are an expert in Joomla, stay away from them ;)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the (good) advice already provided, there is a missing answer to your question: where does the HTML markup come from?

You will find it in one of two places: first check your template overrides (which I think is the case looking at your question), which would be located in

```
/templates/as002035/html/com_users/login/default_logout.php (logout component)
/templates/as002035/html/mod_login/ (login|logout module)
```

if they are not present, then the default Joomla layouts are in

```
/components/com_users/views/...
/modules/mod_login/tmpl
```

### Added after clarification below, this is the answer the the comments.

you're missing a class "button" so the line of the module should be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Log out" class="button btn btn-primary" name="Submit">
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Log out" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit">
```

(see the added "button"?). Did you find the template ? is it in the overrides? if you can just make that change you'll get the module fixed. As for the component logout form, http://www.guhlmotors.com/index.php?option=com_users

```
<button class="button btn" type="submit">Log out</button>
```

instead of

```
<button class="button" type="submit">Log out</button>
```

Comment: Thank you ricardo. I'm trying to locate the HTML markup code in those files but no luck. They are still PHP files. I'm trying to figure out how to send screenshots. I want t post one with firebug as well so you can see the problem I see. It seems the log out button is in form of "input" I fixed the member registering problem so if you want to see for yourself just register to the site and log in and you will see the log out button - or lack thereof I should say lol

Comment: great, I need 10 reputation to post images. Sorry, no screenshot I guess

Comment: all right, I favoured your question so now you have the points :-)
you won't find just html markup, the html is always generated from php files in Joomla. Ok so I registered (user test3) , logged in, then on the homepage I see the logout button. Not pretty, but working.

Comment: right that's the problem lol the not pretty part. it should match the rest of them. Not sure why it doesnt

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I think that should fix it as well. I think my problem is finding this darn code line in a labyrinth that joomla is. smh. You wouldn't happen to know where would this be, would you? I looked everywhere. But I'll keep looking. I'll update if I find it

Comment: WOOHOO!!!! Found it and fix it! Thank you so much for your help. Now if I could bother you one last time. Sorry, I can't let you go now. You seem to know joomla pretty well. Have you looked at the search form alignment? I provided a pic as well. But if you want to see it for yourself just go back to the site and try searching for anything. Watch the alignment on the results page and the darn button again :(

Comment: quick update. I fixed the results message label. It is aligned right under the textbox. Have not tried on other browsers but I am hopeful. The last thing and I will be done is gtting that button up a little, which I can't seem to find it in the css files even with firebug. If I move it I move EVERY button accross the site up as well. But although that is not a big deal to me, wwhat I really want is to label it. I want it to say "Search" But neither CSS or PHP is doing it for me.

Comment: Sorry those are two new different questions, the first: add a new css class and create a rule, look up a css positioning crash course or the w3c docs on the rules: marginTop, display, float; 2nd: it's definitely in your php (components/com_search/view or its override under /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_search ..

Comment: I figured it out. But I do thank you very much. You were great help